# How to properly use getIntExtra?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'am trying to pass an integer between two activities.

Activity1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
int num1=40;
intent.putExtra("num1", num1);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int num = intent.getIntExtra("num1", 1);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tb_01);
tv.setText(num);
```

When I start the app, and press the button which starts the method(1. codeblock) it crashes saying: "unfortunately, the program stopped."
It works fine when I send strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without a stacktrace this is only a guess but i bet this is the problem

```
tv.setText(num);
```

here you are trying to use the number as a resource ID which will not exist so if you want to display the number as text in your text view you need to do

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(num))
```

that will give you a string of the number you passed

Answer (score 3):

You will need to change

```
tv.setText(num);
```

to

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(num));
```

`TextView.setText(int)` will set the text of a resource by integer id, which would more than likely fail, as your `num` wouldn't have a corresponding resource.

Comment: Good catch guys. It seems this was a tie :P

Comment: tyczj was 13 seconds faster ;)

Comment: Haha! yeah? How do you see the exact time?

Comment: Hover the mouse over the time period of the "answered ...... ago", gives you utc.